# Regular expression to match attribute name in xml element

Tags: regex, xml, match

I've the following regular expressions to match:

```
<string attribute=b>x</string> is matched by : (?<range3>[\w\d\-\:]+)[ ]*=[ ]*[\w\d\-\:]+

<string attribute='b'>x</string> is matched by (?<range1>[\w\d\-\:]+)[ ]*=[ ]*'[^']*'

<string attribute="b">x</string> is matched by (?<range2>[\w\d\-\:]+)[ ]*=[ ]*"[^"]*"
```

This works fine, however the following is also matched:

```
  <string>attribute=b</string>

  <string>attribute='b'</string>

  <string>attribute="b"</string>
```

What regular expression do I need to use to **only** match the first three examples?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066

Comment: Thanks for the link to that article. (But why a down-vote ?)

Comment: I didn't down-vote. But I can see why one would from the lack of effort shown in your question. If you *do* want to use regex, read up on [greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
    (?=\S+?>\w+<\S+?)(?<range3>[\w\d\-\:]+)[ ]*=[ ]*[\w\d\-\:]+
```

Added a positive lookahead to check for >x<.Works now.